# If cells from two spreadsheets are equal, subtract 1 from another set of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help adapting this map so that instead of emptying the row, to subtract 1 from the values for each row on columns 0,2,4,6.

*UPDATED for clarification:

I am looking for the function to work as follows: if a name in SpreadsheetA matches any in SpreadsheetB, subtract 1 from the corresponding grade column of a name, such that in any given row

if col1 equals any value from the SpreadsheetB range, -1 from col0
if col3 equals any value from the SpreadsheetB range, -1 from col2
if col5 equals any value from the SpreadsheetB range, -1 from col4
if col7 equals any value from the SpreadsheetB range, -1 from col6.

Perhaps I could just create separate maps for each of the above?  My apologies for any confusion.
[SpreadsheetAstart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgxRa.png) [SpreadsheetBstart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4dCo.png) [SpreadsheetBfinish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGtdn.png)

```js
function removeNotReturning() {
var ssNR = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpeadsheetA).getSheetByName("Not returning").getRange("A2:A10");
var ssNRv = ssNR.getValues().flat();
var ssCP = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetB).getSheetByName("Master").getRange("B2:I10");
var ssCPv = ssCP.getValues();
ssCPv = ssCPv.map(nRow => {
var nameExists = [nRow[1],nRow[3],nRow[5],nRow[7]].some(nName => ssNRv.includes(nName));
if (nameExists) nRow.fill("");
return nRow;
});
ssCP.setValues(ssCPv);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information there's probably an easier approach

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Now, I noticed that your question had been changed. I deeply apologize that I noticed your changed question now. I was surprised by this. From your changed question, I understood that my answer was not useful for your updated question. I deeply apologize that my first answer was not useful for your actual situation. For your updated question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If this was not useful again, I apologize again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (nameExists) nRow.fill("");
```

#### To:

```
if (nameExists) [0, 2, 4, 6].forEach(i => nRow[i] -= 1);
```

- By this modification, when `nameExists` is `true`, `1` is reduced from the element of `[0, 2, 4, 6]` instead of `nRow.fill("")`.
- In this case, if the cell value is not the number, `#NUM!` is returned. Please be careful about this.
- If your cells include the string, please modify as follows.

  ```
    if (nameExists) [0, 2, 4, 6].forEach(i => nRow[i] = isNaN(nRow[i]) ? nRow[i] : nRow[i] - 1);
  ```

### Added:

From your updated question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function removeNotReturning() {
  var srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your source Spreadsheet ID.
  var srcSheetName = "Not returning";
  var dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your destination Spreadsheet ID.
  var dstSheetName = "Master";

  var [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [[srcSpreadsheetId, srcSheetName], [dstSpreadsheetId, dstSheetName]].map(([id, name]) => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name));
  var obj = srcSheet.getRange("A2:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => (o[a] = true, o), {});
  var range = dstSheet.getRange("B2:I" + dstSheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues()
  values.forEach(r => r.forEach((c, j) => {
    if (obj[c]) r[j - 1] -= 1;
  }));
  range.setValues(values);
}
```